# Toast inheriting theme background

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-theme, android-styles

I'm having an issue with developing on Android that I have tested on multiple devices and am having the same issues on all devices.

I'm creating a style named SplashTheme, in which I am setting android:background to a green color which matches my app identity. The issue I am having is whenever I create a Toast in this activity, the Toast is partially green. I have tried removing the styling to android:background and it resolves the issue, however, I am needing to style the background in that way.

Any ideas as to why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<item name="android:background">@color/your_color</item>
```

Do:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/your_color</item>
```

Comment: Works beautifully, didn't understand the issues of using background over the other attributes. Thank you!